# перебор массива с работай над объектами

Tags: javascript, массивы

у меня есть форма с полями, я хочу сделать при нажатии кнопки перебор полей, чтобы при отсутствии текста в поле, добавить ему красный `border` и текст внутри, как сделать такой перебор?

через `for` у меня почему то не работает

```js
let btn_1 = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn_1.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.input_1'));
    
        for (let i = 0 ; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        if (!inputs[i]) {
            inputs.style.border = "1px solid red";
            inputs.value = "Заполните поле";
            };
        };
};
```

```html
<form>
      <input type="text" class="input_1">
      <input type="text" class="input_1">
      <button class="btn" type="button">отправить</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: Хочу заметить, что не может быть два элемента с одинаковым индикатором (id).

Comment: required по моему в css, на js проверить на пустоту и добавить в случае совпадения класс какой то

Comment: @MaximLensky, я и так выставил `required`, но из за особенности кода в js, эта функция перестала работать, да и стилистика не та, которая нужна у дефолтного предупреждения. в js я и так получил все поля в массив, я не знаю как проверить каждое и присвоить ему стили

Comment: по моему if(value === " ") {тут надо что то сделать } наверно так - хотя не проверял

Comment: Так вы проверяете существует ли элемент, а не значение. ```if (!inputs[i])``` тут забыли ```value```, ```if (!inputs[i].value)```.

Comment: И мне кажется лучше менять не ```value```, что поле не заполнено, а ```placeholder```.

Comment: @OliverPatterson так вы же тоже самое в ответе сделали - я просто не написал el.value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>
{
  e.preventDefault();
  
  [...form.elements].forEach((el) =>
  {
    if (el.tagName != 'INPUT')
    {
      return;
    }
    
    el.classList.toggle('is--required', el.value == '')
  });
});
```

```css
.is--required
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="input_1">
  <input type="text" class="input_1">
  <button class="btn">отправить</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: Скорее всего класс имеет не правильное описание действия, но главное же суть?)

Comment: мне главное, чтобы работало и понятно было)

Comment: @Joker вот видишь - ну я не так объяснил -

Comment: @OliverPatterson, спасибо, немного переделал под свой вариант, но работает, благодарю)